# Manipulating tr's child elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tr

I just got stuck again, perhaps someone else can spot the problem easier. The 1st tr's children (such as table cells) don't change background on hovering with this code:

```
$("#target tr:eq(1).find("*")").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background", "#fff"); 
        })


<table id="target">
<tr><td\>
content 
</td></tr>
<tr><td\>
content 
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is it the quotes?

Comment: Just add a colon to css("background", "#fff"); })
See answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$("#target tr:eq(1)").find("*").hover(function () {
                    //^^ move find outside the seletor
    $(this).css("background", "#fff");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3WQ9y/)

:eq() index starts from `0` if you want 1st tr us `.eq(0)`

---

Get back old color

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3WQ9y/2/)

```
$("#target tr:eq(1)").find("*").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background", "#fff");
},function(){
    $(this).css("background", "blue"); //get old color back
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Great, except now it seems the hovering doesn't work on an image inside that table row. But it somehow works when hovering on an empty table cell.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out by targeting the table row rather than its children, and thanks again, really helped.